# create binding text and data in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to link these three words to their alternative number in excel,

> `not started`, `in progress`, and `done` to `0`, `0.5`, and `1` respectively.

I tried to create a list of states and used them in column A, the same as the following image.

[image]

then I wrote a simple code in column B respectivly to achieve my desire like this:

```
=LOOKUP(A1,{"not started","in Progress","done"},{0,0.5,1})
```

(A1 changed to A2 and A3, respectively)

But the result was weird, and I do not have any idea what is my misunderstanding about the function `lookup`.
here is the result:
[image]
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your formula doesn't work because the elements of first array have to be sorted, so `=LOOKUP(A1,{"done","in Progress","not started"},{1,0.5,0})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [LOOKUP Vector form](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lookup-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb#bmvector_form):

> The values in lookup_vector must be placed in ascending order: ..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ..., **A-Z**, FALSE, TRUE; otherwise, LOOKUP might not return the correct value.

So, it should be: `LOOKUP(A1,{"done","in progress","not started"},{1,0.5,0})` with 'd', 'i', 'n'.

If you don't want to bother with figuring out the correct order, you could use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX({0,0.5,1},MATCH(A1,{"not started","in progress","done"},0))
```

Comment: You might profit from the newer dynamic array features by replacing the single cell reference by a complete range indication; see my expansion on your valid answer  +:) (including the modified alternative) @ourobos1

Answer (score 1):

Why not IFS.

```
=IFS(A1="not started",0,A1="in progress",0.5,A1="done",1)
```

Comment: Valid solution to these three search possibilities +:) - Fyi Might be interested in my (late) answer referring to ouroboros1, too. @nicholasfor

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @ouroboros1 's answer, you might profit from the newer
dynamic array features by replacing the *single cell reference* by a **range** like e.g. `A1:A100`

```
=LOOKUP(A1:A100,{"done","in progress","not started"},{1,0.5,0})
```

and

```
    =INDEX({0,0.5,1},MATCH(A1:A100,{"not started","in progress","done"},0))
```

---

Furthermore you can even omit the `Index` function in the latter formula by returning
the ordinal numeric findings within the given search array minus 1 and divided by 2:

```
    =(MATCH(A1:A100,{"not started","in progress","done"},0)-1)/2
```

**Note**

*If you don't dispose of versions 2019+|MS365 enter array formulae
via <kbd>**C**trl</kbd><kbd>**S**hift</kbd><kbd>**E**nter</kbd>.*

**Further hints:**

- All examples (including nicholasfor's `IFS` solution) are case insensitive,
- `LookUp` and `IFS` allow wild cards, too
- `LookUp` needs an
  ascending sort order as indicated (`..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ..., A-Z, FALSE, TRUE`).